# How to run jekyll on windows 10?

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm on teamtreehouse.com and they provided us with instruction to getting jekyll on windows http://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/windows/jekyll-windows.html.

I followed it and my start command keep saying 'c:\RubyDevKit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I downloaded the recent version which is the 2.3.1(x64) and I named my Dev kit c:\RubyDevKit like I was asked too, I'm not sure where I went wrong since I am a newbie.

I've been waiting for the past 8 hours for a response from treehouse and nothing, I've even tried google but since I'm a newbie I don't know who to follow when I google.

** Bonus question is it easier to run jekyll on a windows 8 because I have a windows 8 computer also.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you install the x64 devkit: `mingw64-64-4.7.2`? Can you change directory to the appropriate devkit install location (i.e. `cd C:\RubyDevKit`)?  And--if so--did you initialize and install from that location?  And--FWIW--http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ indicates that "The 64-bit versions of Ruby are relatively new on the Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be compatible with it."

Comment: Honestly no, I just had followed the directions they had listed but I didn't download the x64 devkit. So I'll try again and probably not use the 64-bit version. Thanks @orde